# Wp-config error handling

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, configuration

I have been told to add this code to my wp-config file but when I do the php has a syntax error and I'm unsure how to go about fixing it.

Where should I add this code inside the wp-config.php file?

```
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG&#039;, true);
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY&#039;, false);
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG_LOG&#039;, true);
```

Here is where I have inserted the above code, I get an error on the second last line:

```
/**
 * For developers: WordPress debugging mode.
 *
 * Change this to true to enable the display of notices during development.
 * It is strongly recommended that plugin and theme developers use WP_DEBUG
 * in their development environments.
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', false);
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG&#039;, true);
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY&#039;, false);
define(&#039;WP_DEBUG_LOG&#039;, true);

/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Must be

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
```

And you don't need to add `WP_DEBUG` twise, only change its value to `true`.